# change AutoNumber values when inserting rows with UCanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

When using the `executeUpdate` method of UCanAccess, the system always chooses the row number for me. However, after I delete my rows and add new ones, the rows do not start from the beginning (e.g., I deleted 3 rows, then it marks the next 3 rows as `4`, `5`, and `6`). Is there a way I can fix this or name the rows myself? Here is my code:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO myDB2"+ " ( columnRows,  columnA, columnB)"
    + " VALUES ( "+rows+", "+a+", "+b+")");`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resetting the next AutoNumber value**

After deleting rows you can reset the AutoNumber seed values by opening the database in Access and performing a "Compact and Repair Database" operation. UCanAccess is currently unable to reset the seed value itself.

**Inserting arbitrary values into an AutoNumber column**

Starting with version 4.0.2, UCanAccess is able to insert arbitrary positive values into an AutoNumber (Long Integer, Increment) column. For example, with a table named [Client]:

ClientID - AutoNumber
FirstName - Text(50)

we can do

```java
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("DISABLE AUTOINCREMENT ON Client");
st.execute("INSERT INTO Client (ClientID, FirstName) VALUES (123, 'Gord')");
```

For more details, see the blog post [here](http://ucanaccess.blogspot.ca/2017/04/inserting-arbitrary-values-into.html).

Version 4.0.3 (not yet released) extends that capability to allow inserting arbitrary values that are less than or equal to zero.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more specifics of the AutoNumber column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more specifics". Please elaborate on what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry- how exactly do I insert arbitrary values into the AutoNumber column?

Comment: If `ClientID` is an AutoNumber column then UCanAccess 4.0.2 supports `INSERT INTO Client (ClientID, FirstName) VALUES (123, 'Gord')`. Of course, if `ClientID` is also the primary key then the value `123` must not already exist in the table.

Comment: That's what I'm doing but the rows don't use my  values and instead keep increasing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Evan - Sorry, I forgot a step. I have updated my answer.